# How to call Live Template's select menu in PhpStorm?

Tags: phpstorm

I'm watching some video course. An author of the course uses Live Templates in PhpStorm. It looks like pretty comfortable. I have never used it before. See, how it looks like (it's a screen from the video):

[image]

If the author press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the string `You are on a Category/Index page` will be wrapped on a special construction.

I have prepared the same for myself. This is my settings:

[image]

But I can't find hotkey to call context menu like in the previous screen. Please, tell me how to call this `Select template` menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shortcut is simple: use whatever you have got there for `Code | Surround with...` -- it will list ALL applicable stuff which includes Live Templates.

[image]

**For Live Templates alone**, that would be <kbd>Ctrl + Alt + J</kbd> on Windows keymap. You can check and change that via `Settings/Preferences | Keymap` -- look for `Other | Surround with Live Template...` action (you may use search field to quickly narrow it down):

[image]

More on Live Templates: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/using-live-templates.html

---

**P.S.** You have not defined "applicable contexts" on your last screenshot (with the actual Live Template).

Comment: Oohh, thank you. I don't know what is this (I mean `applicable contexts`) I will check it just now.)

Comment: That is scopes/languages where such Live Template can be used. E.g. PHP is a big one, but you can limit certain templates to be applicable only in comments etc.

Comment: Ooo!! Now I see! I understand why it did not work for me! `Alt + ctrl + t` it's what I need. But it is hotkey for call Linux terminal)) Linux command, of course, overlaps it) Thank you very much))

Comment: Maybe you are not using the Linux-compatible keymap? In any case: the shortcut for that and more specific `Surround with Live Template` action can be changed in `Settings/Preferences | Keymap`